# EasyRTC - How to allow automatically user media permission

Tags: webrtc, easyrtc

When `easyrtc` connect in browser appear permission to active webcam and microphone,
my question is how to set allow automatically user media permission every single browser ?

[image]

Comment: It wouldn't be "permission" if sites could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox you can select Always in the popup.

In Chrome, you can start it with [--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#use-fake-ui-for-media-stream). There are some policies too: [VideoCaptureAllowed](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#VideoCaptureAllowed) and [VideoCaptureAllowedUrls](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#VideoCaptureAllowedUrls).

Comment: Thank you for the answer